# NullPointerException in ObjectMapper in Spark Cluster Mode on AWS EMR

Tags: java, apache-spark, jackson, hadoop-yarn, elastic-map-reduce

I am getting `nullpointer` exception in this line (running spark in cluster mode (yarn) on aws emr) but runs fine in client mode (with master as local)

```
Map<String, Object> json = (Map<String, Object>) mapper.readValue(line, Map.class);
```

This is the stacktrace of the executor:

```
18/04/17 12:33:16 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.LRUMap.get(LRUMap.java:47)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromClass(TypeFactory.java:707)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._constructType(TypeFactory.java:387)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:354)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2161)
```

I am using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You need to post the code of your driver, and the transformation you're making through the call to object mapper

Answer (score 0):

@Ernest Kiwele Found the issue. Its was because I was importing 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` instead of `com.cloudera.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`